# Best way to use/practice of using parentheses in java

Tags: java, sonarqube, parentheses

While working on Sonar static code analyzer I found some confusing (may be only to me) statement by Sonar on using parentheses.

Below are the few code snippets where Sonar says remove useless parentheses:

```
line>1  String auth = "Basic "+ com.somepackge.someMethod(((String) (parent.proxyUsername+ ":" + parent.proxyPassword)));
line>2  return rawtime.length() > 3 ? (rawtime.substring(0, rawtime.length() - 2) + rawtime.substring(rawtime.length() - 2, rawtime.length()).toLowerCase()) : rawtime;
```

though I have replaced above lines with below one to keep Sonar calm :) :

```
Line>3 String auth = "Basic "+ com.somepackge.someMethod((String) (parent.proxyUsername+ ":" + parent.proxyPassword));

Line>4 return  rawtime.length() > 3 ? rawtime.substring(0, rawtime.length() - 2) + rawtime.substring(rawtime.length() - 2, rawtime.length()).toLowerCase() : rawtime;
```

So the reason for discussing this question is:

1. Actually using braces/parentheses are way to reduce the confusion so why to remove those parentheses.
2. What is best way to use parentheses while writing any complex statement in java.

See the line>1 and Line>4 here I think

`(String) (parent.proxyUsername+ ":" + parent.proxyPassword)`

this part of code should have the braces to avoid confusions but what Sonar  expect is something like:

```
   (String) parent.proxyUsername+ ":" + parent.proxyPassword
```

Any suggestion would be a great help. I got some links regarding this question but those were not much helpful.

Comment: Well, the parentheses on the first line are clearly redundant. It like writing `System.out.println(("Hello world"))` - you're already marking the start and end of the parameter by the outer `()`, so what do the inner ones really do?

Comment: This code looks like if's already obfuscated/minimized.

Comment: I'd write the second line as an explicit conditional anyway; it's pretty hard to read with or without the brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### First snippet

```
String auth = "Basic "+ someMethod(((String) (parent.proxyUsername+ ":" + parent.proxyPassword)));
```

You could rewrite it as:

```
String auth = "Basic "+ someMethod(parent.proxyUsername+ ":" + parent.proxyPassword);
```

because the string concatenation operator already does a string conversion. Unless you want a `ClassCastException` thrown when `proxyUsername` or `proxyPassword` are not Strings?

#### Second snippet

```
return rawtime.length() > 3 ? (rawtime.substring(0, rawtime.length() - 2) + rawtime.substring(rawtime.length() - 2, rawtime.length()).toLowerCase()) : rawtime;
```

The parenthesis is indeed unnecessary but the statement is quite unreadable. If you want to keep using the ternary operator I would suggest splitting the statement across lines:

```
return rawtime.length() > 3
       ? rawtime.substring(0, rawtime.length() - 2) + rawtime.substring(rawtime.length() - 2, rawtime.length()).toLowerCase()
       : rawtime;
```

or you could revert the condition:

```
return rawtime.length() <= 3 ? rawtime :
       rawtime.substring(0, rawtime.length() - 2) + rawtime.substring(rawtime.length() - 2, rawtime.length()).toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Line 1` has redundant parentheses, but `Line 2`'s parentheses add clarity to the ternary statement.

Whether or not the extra parenthesis in `2` are useful is up for debate - but there's no reason not to remove the redundant ones in `1`.

Generally it's best to use extra parenthesis to convey your intent about what the code should do, or to remove ambiguity in the order that things occur.

Answer (score 0):

There is a semantic difference between these two versions:

`(String) (parent.proxyUsername+ ":" + parent.proxyPassword)`

`(String) parent.proxyUsername+ ":" + parent.proxyPassword`

In the first, the second set of () already evaluates to a `String`, implicitly calling `parent.proxyUsername.toString()` to convert `proxyUsername` to a `String`. So the cast is redundant and should be removed IMHO. The second version casts `parent.proxyUsername` to `String`, and will throw an exception is it hasn’t got runtime type `String` (only if it is declared a `String` is the cast redundant).

I agree that line 2 and 4 are complicated to read no matter if they have the redundant braces or not. Rewrite if you want clarity. That said, redundant braces are sometimes good for clarity IMHO, I do use them occasionally.

Answer (score -2):

the best way is to put your class that you're casting to in a parentheses then the whole part to be converted in another parentheses, then include this whole code in a container parentheses, your code should look like this e.g ((String)(x+y)).

I hope that was helpful, thanks.

Comment: U r making it more complex.